# Trig sub. Integrating and finding the derivative again

Tags: calculus

I am having trouble checking my work here:

I have this problem

$$\sin^2{x}cos^3{x}dx$$

and through some trig sub I found the derivative. My first step was to rewrite this in the form of:

$$\int sin^2{x}cos^2{x}cos{x}dx$$

$$ = \int sin^2{x}(1-sin^2{x}) * cos{x}dx$$ and u subbing with $sin{x}$

and eventually I found the derivative:

$$\frac{sin^3{x}}{3} - \frac{sin^5{x}}{5} + c$$

but I'm having trouble finding the derivative of that to get back to the original integrand.

$$\frac{d}{dx} = sin^2{x}cos{x} - sin^4{x}cos{x}$$
$$ = cosx(sin^2{x} - sin^4{x})$$

But I'm stuck how to get this back to the original integrand form.

Comment: $\sin^2x-\sin^4 x = \sin^2 x(1-\sin^2 x) = \sin^2 x\cos^2 x$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already there:  $\cos x(\sin^2 x-\sin^4 x)=\cos x\sin^2 x(1-\sin^2 x)=\cos x\sin^2 x\cos^2 x$.